# Having problems sorting items in a listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting

I am reading a list of high scores for my game from a text file using StreamReader. I am then sorting it using .Sort()

I converted it to an array and passed it into a list box on a form in the game.
The score is saved to the text file in a string (score+" - "+username)

```
public frmHighScores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> scores = new List<string>();
        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("High Scores.txt");
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            scores.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
        }
        scores.Sort();
        lstScores.Items.AddRange(scores.ToArray());
    }
```

As it is a string the Sort method is only sorting the first number in the score and I'm not sure how to rectify it.

[Here is the image of the sorted list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6atx.png)

I want it to read as follows

```
200
120
105
65
```

Comment: Since it's a string - it's being sorted alphabetically.

Comment: .OrderByDescending(x=>int.Parse(x));

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Dictionary to store these values (score and username). This will eable you to order using a real numeric type. You can build this dictionary by splitting the strings, as follows:

```
public void frmHighScores()
    {
        // Pretend we read this from the file
        List<string> fakeFileValues = new List<string>() { "20 steve", "100 john", "25 jane" };
        Dictionary<int, string> scores = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (string s in fakeFileValues)
        {
            // Better ways to do this, just expanding for clarity
            string[] split = s.Split(' ');
            scores.Add(int.Parse(split[0]), split[1]);
        }

        // You can then order by a real numeric value
        scores.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
    }
```

Comment: I used a variation of your suggestion, thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You could use the LINQ OrderByDescending extension method and pass inn the value which comes before the "-" sign, something like that:

```
scores = scores.OrderByDescending(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]).Trim());
```